# using math with XMLHttpRequest data

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I have been asked if I can use some form data and present it in HTML.

I need to add up the LOADS data/values and multiply it by the RATE data/values, I thought this would have worked but its not showing anything in my browser?

Where am I going wrong?

I'm new to JavaScript and I have HTML/CSS skills. I know jQuery is probably the best way to do this sort of stuff but I don't know it.

```
<html>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xmltest.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var k=xmlDoc.x[1].getElementsByTagName("LOADS");
var J=xmlDoc.x[1].getElementsByTagName("RATE");
  { 
  document.write("<tr ><td>");
  document.write(k*J);
  document.write("</td><tr>");
  }

document.write("</table>");

</script>
</html>



XML file

<MULTILOAD_TICKET>
<TICKET>
<DATE>12/11/12</DATE>
<ADDRESS>123 FAKE STREET</ADDRESS>
<RATE>300</RATE>
<LOADS>3</LOADS>
<CUSTOMER>Columbia Ales</CUSTOMER>
<ORDERID>BBKHJ1001</ORDERID>
<DRIVER>BOB</DRIVER>
<VEHICAL_REG>UJ78 JHE</VEHICAL_REG>
<MATERIAL>SPOIL</MATERIAL>
<SIG>URL</SIG>
</TICKET>

<TICKET>
<DATE>12/11/12</DATE>
<ADDRESS>123 FAKE STREET</ADDRESS>
<RATE>300</RATE>
<LOADS>6</LOADS>
<CUSTOMER>Columbia Ales</CUSTOMER>
<ORDERID>BBKHJ1001</ORDERID>
<DRIVER>JACK</DRIVER>
<VEHICAL_REG>EU78 JHD</VEHICAL_REG>
<MATERIAL>SPOIL</MATERIAL>
<SIG>URL</SIG>
</TICKET>

<TICKET>
<DATE>15/11/12</DATE>
<ADDRESS>123 FAKE STREET</ADDRESS>
<RATE>300</RATE>
<LOADS>5</LOADS>
<CUSTOMER>Columbia Ales</CUSTOMER>
<ORDERID>BBKHJ1001</ORDERID>
<DRIVER>BOB</DRIVER>
<VEHICAL_REG>UJ78 JHE</VEHICAL_REG>
<MATERIAL>SPOIL</MATERIAL>
<SIG>URL</SIG>
</TICKET>

</MULTILOAD_TICKET>
```

Answer (score 1):

`k` and `J` refer to a collection of elements, so you can't just multiply them together.

You need to loop through the collections, access their `textContent` (or `innerText` depending on browser version), convert to numbers (`parseInt` or `parseFloat` as needed), multiply them and then add them to a running total. Finally, at the end, you can output the total.